# Как сделать роутинг с ui route из ссылки выпадающего списка?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Есть файл `navbar.jade` в котором описан выпадающий список с ссылками следующим образом

```
.navbar-element
    dropdown(title='{{ navbar.username }}', array="navbar.profilemenu", class='usermenu', pos='right')
```

Как сделать переход с каждой ссылки на другие страницы из этого списка через `ui-sref`?

Comment: какой Html На выходе?

Comment: Вероятно надо передать значение ui-sref в функцию dropdown. По двум строчкам кода сложно представить желаемый результат.